# Optimize SQL date function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, optimization

I’ve written a function (Oracle SQL) that calculates the number of business days between two dates based on different countries’ calendars. It needs to be run thousands of times, so speed is very important.
You input a startdate, an enddate and the name for the given calender for example ‘US’, ‘UK’ and so on. The input parameters are passed through in different SQL’s, but right now I’m still testing.
The function uses a holiday table to look up non-business days between the days. The table contains all weekends and national holidays in different countries. The problem is that the function is quite slow, despite using cursors. Does any have any tips, on how to make the function faster? I’m suspecting the select query in the function to be the problem. I might be wrong but nevertheless I don’t know what to do about it.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test (in_dt1         DATE,
                                                in_dt2         DATE,
                                                in_Calender    VARCHAR)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    Count_days    NUMBER := 0;
    beg_dt        DATE;
    End_dt        DATE;
    Curr_dt       DATE;
    Cursor_dato   DATE;

    CURSOR C1
    IS
      SELECT b.holiday
        FROM calendars a
             INNER JOIN holidays b ON a.calik = b.calik
       WHERE a.cal = in_Calender AND holiday >= in_dt1 AND holiday <= in_dt2;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c1;

   beg_dt := LEAST (in_dt1, in_dt2);
   End_dt := GREATEST (in_dt1, in_dt2);

   Curr_dt := beg_dt + 1;

  <<OUTER>>
   WHILE Curr_dt <= End_dt
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO cursor_dato;

      WHILE cursor_dato IS NULL
      LOOP
         Count_days := Count_days + 1;
         Curr_dt := Curr_dt + 1;
         EXIT OUTER WHEN Curr_dt = End_dt + 1;
      END LOOP;

      WHILE Curr_dt < cursor_dato
      LOOP
         Count_days := Count_days + 1;
         Curr_dt := Curr_dt + 1;
         EXIT OUTER WHEN Curr_dt = End_dt;
      END LOOP;

      IF Curr_dt > cursor_dato
      THEN
         Count_days := Count_days + 1;
      END IF;

      Curr_dt := Curr_dt + 1;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c1;

   RETURN Count_days;
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select trunc (end_dt) - trunc(beg_dt) from dual;
```

gives you number of days between two dates.

```
select count(1) from holidays where holiday >= beg_dt AND holiday <= end_dt;
```

gives you number of holidays between two dates.

First - second give you your result. Without cursors, loops and so on.

So something like:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test (in_dt1         DATE,
                                     in_dt2         DATE,
                                     in_Calender    VARCHAR2,
                                     p_country      varchar2)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
      Count_days    NUMBER := 0;
      beg_dt        DATE;
      End_dt        DATE;
      count_holidays number := 0;
    begin

      beg_dt := LEAST (in_dt1, in_dt2);
      End_dt := GREATEST (in_dt1, in_dt2);

      count_days := trunc(end_dt) - trunc(beg_dt);

      select count(1) 
      into count_holidays 
      from holidays 
      where holiday >= beg_dt
      AND holiday <= end_dt
      and country = p_country;

      return Count_days - count_holidays;
    end;
```

I've added parameter for country to count proper holidays.

Comment: why select from dual when you could just do: `count_days := trunc(beg_dt) - trunc(end_dt);`? Best avoid pointless context switching if you can, especially if performance is a consideration! Also, why `count(1)`? [`count(*)` is faster!](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789#25335122556076) *{;-)

Comment: @Boneist you're absolutely right. Just copied code that I post as a SQL

Comment: @Boneist I believe the count(*) vs count(1) controversy has been debunked in recent versions of oracle. At least in 11g and onwards.

Comment: @Boneist you mean the conclusive proof that count(\*) has 33% few steps than count(1) due to not having to release the shift key during typing?  Due to the inherent degree of parallelism in typing, some of those extra steps occur nearly simultaneously, and parallel processing can often achieve greater performance compared to pure sequential processing, so I disbelieve the claim of a 33% improvement for count(\*) over count(1).  Still I prefer count(\*) for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @Sentinel it was a purely tongue-in-cheek response. However, count(*) is, IMHO, more semantically correct. Plus it's what the optimiser converts Count(1) to anyway, so... But, clearly YMMV! *{;-)

Comment: Hi, and sorry about the late reply. Thank you so much for your answers and input. Your Solution works, and it's at least twice as fast as mine. I guess I got caught up in using Cursor so I over-complicated the solution.